# How to restrict draggable pushpin outside of map visible area

Tags: bing-maps

I am using Bing Maps v7 and created  a draggable pushpin. i have taken code from here.

http://www.garzilla.net/vemaps/Draggable-Push-Pins-with-Bing-Maps-7.aspx

I need to restrict the drag outside of visible map area.

I have a defined map area with zoom pan disabled and with draggable pin where user can put there pin.

**issue:** pushpin is draggable outside of map then no option to get that back.

Answer (score 0):

On the `Pushpin` class, you have several events to manage the action that are done on drag start, drag and drag end, see on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427615.aspx

So, to be simple, all you have to do is to handle the event of your choice (in your case, I would recommend to use `drag` on the pushpin) and cancel the event or just modify by yourself the location of the pushpin.

See a live example where the pushpin is restricted to a minimal latitude value (you can update the drag event to be able to restrict to a specific area based on your current map view):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Bing Maps AJAX V7 - Restricted draggable pushpin</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = null;
      var minLatitude = 49;

      function getMap()
      {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), 
        {
            credentials: 'YOURKEY',
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(50, 3),
            zoom: 6
        });
      }

      function addDraggablePushpin()
      {
        var pushpinOptions = {draggable: true}; 
        var pushpin= new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), pushpinOptions); 
        map.entities.push(pushpin);

        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'drag', function() {
            var loc = pushpin.getLocation();

            // Verify if it's in a certain area if not, cancel event
            if(loc.latitude < minLatitude) {
                pushpin.setLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(minLatitude, loc.longitude));
            }
        });
      }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="getMap();">
      <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
      <div>
         <input type="button" value="AddDraggablePushpin" onclick="addDraggablePushpin();" />
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```